# How should I make an array from my checkboxes?

Tags: php, html

So I want to make an array from all my checkboxes and later check whether they are checked or not.
Currently I am trying the following way, which is not working:

```
<?php
  $napok[] = $_POST['napok[]'];

  isset($_POST['napok[0]'])
?>



<form class="asd" id="checkbox" action="index.php"  method="post">
    <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
              <th>1.</th>
              <th>2.</th>
              <th>3.</th>
              <th>4.</th>
              <th>5.</th>
              <th>6.</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Hétfő</th>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="he1" for="he1">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he2" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="he2" for="he2">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he3" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="he3" for="he3">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he4" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="he4" for="he4">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he5" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="he5" for="he5">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he6" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="he6" for="he6">40</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Kedd</th>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="ke1" for="ke1">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke2" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="ke2" for="ke2">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke3" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="ke3" for="ke3">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke4" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="ke4" for="ke4">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke5" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="ke5" for="ke5">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke6" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="ke6" for="ke6">40</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Szerda</th>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="sze1" for="sze1">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze2" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="sze2" for="sze2">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze3" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="sze3" for="sze3">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze4" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="sze4" for="sze4">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze5" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="sze5" for="sze5">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze6" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="sze6" for="sze6">40</label></td>
            <tr>
              <hr>
              <th>Csütörtök</th>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="csu1" for="csu1">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="csu2" for="csu2">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="csu3" for="csu3">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="csu4" for="csu4">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="csu5" for="csu5">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[]"><label id="csu6" for="csu6">40</label></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Jelentkezés elküldése">
</form>
```

As I said, I want to get an array. It's size should be around 24 elements (24 checkboxes). Later I want to check each one if they are checked or not, but how could I do all these things?

Comment: `= $_POST['napok']` no `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of the main ways to go about it. One way is to define the key:

```
name="napok[he1]"
name="napok[he2]"
```

Then check for them:

```
if(isset($_POST['napok']['he1'])) { }
```

Or set a value:

```
name="napok[]" value="he1"
name="napok[]" value="he2"
```

Then check for it:

```
if(in_array('he1', $_POST['napok'])) { }
```

Also, this is not correct (see above):

```
$napok[] = $_POST['napok[]'];

isset($_POST['napok[0]'])
```

Comment: Woah... Same time!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra `$_POST['napok[]'];` bracket and try to grab all the **checkbox** as an `array` using `$_POST['napok']`. Also you can pass the index of   `napok` array like `napok[he1]`, `napok[he2]` and so on to make it easier while checking which **element** is checked or not?

**Full code:**

```
<form class="asd" id="checkbox" action="?"  method="post">
    <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
              <th>1.</th>
              <th>2.</th>
              <th>3.</th>
              <th>4.</th>
              <th>5.</th>
              <th>6.</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Hétfő</th>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[he1]"><label id="he1" for="he1">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he2" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[he2]"><label id="he2" for="he2">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he3" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[he3]"><label id="he3" for="he3">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he4" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[he4]"><label id="he4" for="he4">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he5" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[he5]"><label id="he5" for="he5">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he6" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[he6]"><label id="he6" for="he6">40</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Kedd</th>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[ke1]"><label id="ke1" for="ke1">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke2" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[ke2]"><label id="ke2" for="ke2">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke3" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[ke3]"><label id="ke3" for="ke3">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke4" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[ke4]"><label id="ke4" for="ke4">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke5" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[ke5]"><label id="ke5" for="ke5">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke6" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[ke6]"><label id="ke6" for="ke6">40</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Szerda</th>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[sze1]"><label id="sze1" for="sze1">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze2" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[sze2]"><label id="sze2" for="sze2">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze3" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[sze3]"><label id="sze3" for="sze3">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze4" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[sze4]"><label id="sze4" for="sze4">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze5" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[sze5]"><label id="sze5" for="sze5">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze6" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[sze6]"><label id="sze6" for="sze6">40</label></td>
            <tr>
              <hr>
              <th>Csütörtök</th>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[csu1]"><label id="csu1" for="csu1">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[csu2]"><label id="csu2" for="csu2">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[csu3]"><label id="csu3" for="csu3">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[csu4]"><label id="csu4" for="csu4">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[csu5]"><label id="csu5" for="csu5">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="napok[csu6]"><label id="csu6" for="csu6">40</label></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Jelentkezés elküldése">
</form>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['napok'])) 
{
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST['napok']); 
    print '</pre>';
}
?>
```

**After Submit:**

```
Array
(
    [he4] => on
    [he6] => on
    [ke2] => on
    [ke5] => on
    [sze5] => on
    [csu3] => on
    [csu4] => on
)
```

Comment: Erm... That doesn't actually answer the question.